# Use groupby keys as indexes of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
                    % Renewable  Energy Supply
Country                                       
China                 19.754910   1.271910e+11
United States         11.570980   9.083800e+10
Japan                 10.232820   1.898400e+10
United Kingdom        10.600470   7.920000e+09
Russian Federation    17.288680   3.070900e+10
Canada                61.945430   1.043100e+10
Germany               17.901530   1.326100e+10
India                 14.969080   3.319500e+10
France                17.020280   1.059700e+10
South Korea            2.279353   1.100700e+10
Italy                 33.667230   6.530000e+09
Spain                 37.968590   4.923000e+09
Iran                   5.707721   9.172000e+09
Australia             11.810810   5.386000e+09
Brazil                69.648030   1.214900e+10
```

I am grouping this dataframe using the Continents each country belongs to and also using the bins obtained by using `pd.cut` on the column `% Renewable` :

```
out, bins = pd.cut(Top15['% Renewable'].values, bins = 5, retbins = True)
grp = Top15.groupby(by = [ContinentDict, out])
```

where,

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
              'United States':'North America', 
              'Japan':'Asia', 
              'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
              'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
              'Canada':'North America', 
              'Germany':'Europe', 
              'India':'Asia',
              'France':'Europe', 
              'South Korea':'Asia', 
              'Italy':'Europe', 
              'Spain':'Europe', 
              'Iran':'Asia',
              'Australia':'Australia', 
              'Brazil':'South America'}
```

Now, I want to create a new dataframe with the same columns as `df` and another column given by 'Country'. The indexes of this new dataframe should be given by groupby objects keys hierarchically ('Continent', 'out'). After hours of trial, I see no way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a multi-index from `continent` and `cut` and assign it back to your data frame:

```
out, bins = pd.cut(Top15['% Renewable'].values, bins = 5, retbins = True)
con = Top15.index.to_series().map(ContinentDict).values

Top15.reset_index(inplace=True)
Top15.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([con, out])
Top15
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way so that all the continent entries would be seen contiguously?

Comment: You can `sort_index()` if that is what you are looking for.